# Why are my two simple Spring REST services returning two different JSON formats, one is a JSON object and the other a JSON string?

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, rest

I have two web services, CREATE and DELETE.  They both work fine, but the JSON result comes back in two different formats.  One is a string and one is a JSON object.

The 'CREATE' function works and displays the success message correctly, like so ...

```
            var formData = {
                dataSourceName:$('#createDS-name').val()
            };
            var sJSON = JSON.stringify(formData);
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "http://localhost:8080/juliet/json/datasource/create",
                data : sJSON,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success : function(msg) {
                    alert("210: msg = "+msg);
                    alert("215: JSON.stringify(msg) = "+JSON.stringify(msg));
                    alert("220: JSON.stringify(msg.message) = "+JSON.stringify(msg.message));
                    $("#successAlert").html("<strong>Success!</strong> "+JSON.stringify(msg.message)+"</div>");
/***/
```

The displayed alerts look like this:

```
210: msg = [object Object]
215: JSON.stringify(msg) = {"success":true,"message":"successfully created DataSource; id = 21"}
220: JSON.stringify(msg.message) = "successfully created DataSource; id = 21"
```

The 'DELETE' function also works, like so ...

```
            $.ajax({
                type : "DELETE",
                url : "http://localhost:8080/juliet/json/datasource/"+dataSourceId,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success : function(msg) {
                    alert("110: msg = "+msg);
                    alert("111: msg.message = "+msg.message);
                    alert("112: msg.success = "+msg.success);
                    alert("115: JSON.stringify(msg) = "+JSON.stringify(msg));
                    alert("120: JSON.stringify(msg.message) = "+JSON.stringify(msg.message));
                    $("#successAlert").html("<strong>Success:</strong> "+JSON.stringify(msg.message));
/***/
```

But results (see line 120 below) displays "undefined".  The alert box results look like this ...

```
110: msg = {"success":true,"message":"Deleted Data Source id '21'."}
111: msg.message = undefined
112: msg.success = undefined
115: JSON.stringify(msg) = "{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"Deleted Data Source id '21'.\"}"
120: JSON.stringify(msg.message) = undefined
```

The only difference I can see in the Spring Java code is one uses RequestMethod.DELETE and the other uses RequestMethod.POST.

Why am I seeing two different results?  One is a JSON String and one is a JSON Object?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json/datasource/{dataSourceId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public ResponseEntity<String> deleteDataSource(@PathVariable("dataSourceId") int dataSourceId) throws Exception {
    boolean bSuccess = false;
    String sRetMsg = "Unknown error.";

    try {
        this.databaseService.deleteDataSource(dataSourceId);
        bSuccess = true;
        sRetMsg = "Deleted Data Source id '"+dataSourceId+"'.";
    } catch (Exception x) {
        bSuccess = false;
        sRetMsg = x.getMessage();
    }

    JSONObject replyObj = new JSONObject();
    replyObj.put("success", bSuccess);
    replyObj.put("message", sRetMsg);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(replyObj.toJSONString(), (bSuccess) ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);    
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/json/datasource/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> createDataSource(@RequestBody String json) throws Exception {
    boolean bSuccess = false;
    String sRetMsg = "Unknown error.";

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jo = null;
    jo = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);
    String dataSourceName = (String)jo.get("dataSourceName");

    if (dataSourceName == null) {

        sRetMsg = "Missing required parameter 'dataSourceName'.";

    } else 
    if (dataSourceName != null) {

        try {
            Integer id = this.databaseService.createDataSource(dataSourceName);
            bSuccess = true;
            sRetMsg = "successfully created DataSource; id = "+id.toString();
        } catch (Exception x) {
            bSuccess = false;
            sRetMsg = "ERROR: "+x.getMessage();
        }

    }
    JSONObject replyObj = new JSONObject();
    replyObj.put("success", bSuccess);
    replyObj.put("message", sRetMsg);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(replyObj.toJSONString(), (bSuccess) ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);        
}
```

Comment: `msg.message` is just a string. when it is present. javascript objects aren't closed. so you can add additional attributes like `message` whenever. What **is** `msg.message` anyway? Where is it coming from? Have you checked the response includes everything you expect? `Unknown error.` instead of `undefined` (for example). This is confusing on the face of it.

Comment: To simplify, both methods are programmed to return the same thing.  A JSON formatted string, success is `true` or `false` and there's a text message.  Example:  `{"success":true,"message":"Appropriate text message"}` ... the problem is, on the browser side, one success function receives `msg` as a string, and the other as a JSON Object.  I don't understand why the two methods return their result in two different formats.

Comment: Try to make the server explicity send data as Content-Type "*/json".